# "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'" error in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-maps, syntax-error

This is the function in which the error appears.

```
func LoadMapRoute(Url:String)
        {


            let url = URL(string: Url)

            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in

                guard error == nil else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let jsonResult = try? (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]),
                    let jsonResponse = jsonResult else {
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                    return
                }

                //Call this method to draw path on map
                self.drawPath(from: polyLineString)
            })
            task.resume()
        }
```

This is the line in which error is shown in guard let = jsonResult

```
  let jsonResponse = jsonResult
```

Comment: `jsonResult` is already unwrapped if the first `guard` line succeeds. And delete also `.allowFragments`.

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer below code:**

```
 guard let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments),let jsonResponse = jsonResult  as? [String: Any] else {
      print("error in JSONSerialization")
      return
}
```

Your `jsonResult` is already unwrapped so no need to unwrapped again.

Thanks

Comment: Why would do something in two steps when it's already done in a single step?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the statement "let jsonResponse = jsonResult". jsonResult is already checked for.